# Android's module with hidden classes

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm creating a new module in android studio, and I want some of the classes to be hidden to outside of the module, I mean, that the classes could just be used internally in the module, but not externally. Is it possible? How could I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `protected` ... ?

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem. I have created a module, that has its packages and classes. And I want that some of that classes and packages can't be accessed from another android's module. protected would just be useful if creating a class inside a class, which is not the case.

Comment: Regardless of whether you succeed or not, other modules will *always* be able to access them via reflection.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My goal is to keep the module easy to use, so when another developer wants to use that module, it could use a limited number of classes, achieving the same result as with public/private methods in a class, but extended to a whole android studio module.

Comment: Ugh... annotations maybe? No quality idea yet really, sorry for not providing a decent answer yet :/

Comment: Only expose what you intent to expose and keep the rest package-private. Though you might not be able to use sub packages extensively.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. How could I create a private package in a module in android studio? Is there something like expose=false (like services)? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I doubt it's possible to have module-visibility, but the closest you can use is package-visibility, for which you do the following:

Don't make the classes you intend to hide 'public'. Keep the default visibility, which is only seen within classes of the same package. Other public classes within this same package can act as your external interface to your module.

```
class PrivateToPackageInModule {
}

public class InterfaceOfModule {
    private PrivateToPackageInModule ptpim;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  I would like to keep classes private to the module, not to a package within the module.  Is this possible?

Comment: @DBCrocky, I've edited the answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that happens to stumble upon this post, there is now a keyword called `internal` which offers exactly the functionality that OP was looking for.

[Documentation link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html)